# Jquery: How do I unhide a specific div, depending on what option is selected in a select widget?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find the best way to display text corresponding to specific options in a select widget. I'm thinking I can just populate multiple divs with text, each div corresponding to an option in a select widget and initially setting them them with "display: none". Then with Jquery I would unset a specific div to "display: none", depending on which option is selected. However, I'm new to Jquery and am not sure where to start. Can someone point me in the right direction and/or give me suggestions on a better way to do this?

Comment: First you have to think about how to relate an option to a div.

Comment: the various options would have attribute "value=1, value=2, etc..." The divs would have id=1, id=2, etc...  I'm thinking I could use this to pair them?

Comment: what do you mean by a select widget? the `<select>` tag or an actual jquery widget?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the select tag itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually solve the problem like this

```
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div class="my-div-class" id="my-div-id-1">blah 1</div>
<div class="my-div-class" id="my-div-id-2">blah 2</div>
<div class="my-div-class" id="my-div-id-3">blah 3</div>
```

And then I'll have this piece of jquery code execute

```
$('#select').change(function() {
  $('.my-div-class:visible').hide();
  $('#my-div-id-' + $('#select').val()).show();
});
```

These are just examples. You can generalise as much as you like...

Comment: thats a bad way to use jquery :) the main reason jquery was developed was to not have to use onchange attr ,onclick etccc but right answer otherwise :)

Comment: Lukas: Great. This makes sense to me. For the benefit of others, that last curly brace needs to be a closed parenthesis. Thanks again!